# Javascript Class vs. "List" of Functions in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, class

I'm kind of new in programming and I'm currently wondering myself what is the benefit of class vs a simple "list" of related functions in NodeJs.

As very simplified example, I guess I would create a user like this if I'd use Class:

```
class User {
    constructor(email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    validateEmail() {
        // whatever function that checks if this.email is valid
        if (this.email === 'notValid') {
            throw new Error();
        }
        return this;
    }

    create() {
        this.validateEmail();
        // whatever function that inserts user in the database
        return user;
    }
}

const newUser = new User('test@test.com');
const user = newUser.create();
```

And I would do something like this with what I call a "list" of related functions :

```
const validateEmail = email => {
    // whatever function that checks if valid email
    if (email === 'notValid') {
        throw new Error();
    }
    return true;
};

const createUser = email => {
    if (validateEmail(email)) {
        // whatever function that inserts the user in the database
        return user;
    }
};

const user = createUser('test@test.com');
```

The second way seems to me that it can ends with a little less code. And don't even have to instatiate the class.

Let's say I have a node API, with multiple "User" routes and controllers. I guess I have to instantiate the User Class every time a User routes/controllers is called, right ? As a beginner, this does not sound "optimized" to me... But I'm surely missing something...

Thank for your help

Comment: I'd suggest you do some reading on the benefits of object oriented design and architecture.  This is a HUGE topic which you can read entire books on.  Simple examples may be similar with object oriented design or not, but more involved examples are orders of magnitude simpler with object oriented design.  Look up the words "encapsulation", "inheritance", "polymorphism", "modularity", "data abstraction", "namespace" and "reusability".  And, search for "benefits of object oriented design" and read.

Comment: And, of course, not every piece of code is best put into an object design.  Some problems are just procedural.  Object oriented design matches up best when there are a set of operations that all operate on a set of shared data.  Look at a window object in a GUI with a lot of methods for operating on the window.  It's a natural for OO design.  But, a function to decrypt a string may just be a procedural problem.

Comment: I personally never (or rather rarely) use `class`es, because they are hard to serialize / deserialize. Instead I use a regular function that returns objects as a "constructor" and I collect functions working on those objects under a "namespace". That really worked well so far (I also use Typescript to enforce that structure)

Comment: https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/insights/2019/onepattern using classes allows your team to draw out a design in 5 minutes. It is very powerful.  Even when not needed, use classes and wire up business classes through constructors and pass DTO classes/request/response/databaseObjects through methods.  Separate how business/functions are wired up from the execution and it makes maintenance much faster in a team of 3+ developers.

Answer (score 0):

Classes tie data (properties on `this`, the instance) to functionality (functions on the internal prototype of every instance).

If you don't ever have data that makes sense to be associated with an instance, there's not much point in having a class. Here, you *do* have data (the email string) *and* a related function (`validateEmail`), so a class is a possible option, though it's much better when there are more properties and more functions involved. (If there's only *one* property, and the property is only there so it can be called with that one function, a class does indeed seem unnecessarily verbose.)

One benefit of such a class is that, once you have an instance, you can pass that instance around to any other module (or scope), and that module can call functions *related* to the instance, without having to import the equivalent standalone function. For example, imagine if the consumer of your User class was in a different module, and the consumer wants to be able to create users *and* validate them. Then, the module that exports the bulk of the User code would either have to

(1) Export many standalone functions (which could get a bit tedious and hard to manage), or

(2) Export *only* a class

Being able to export just a Class and have any users of the class or its instances use class-related methods is quite handy - that way, you don't have to pass around multiple values every time you need to use a User-related function.

Imagine if module A needs to be able to create a user, module B needs to be able to verify a user, and module C needs to be able to check to see if a user has been verified or not yet. If the main User file created and exported standalone functions for each of these things, and each consuming module imported what they needed to call, things would be a bit ugly. But if the main User file created and exported a Class, it would be trivial: the creator of a User (module A) would import the class, instantiate an object `const user = new User('a@a.com')`, and pass it along to module B, which could then call `user.validateEmail()` (no imports necessary). Then eventually the user instance gets passed along to module C, which calls `user.checkIfUserIsValidated()` (again, no imports necessary).

With the Class method, having an object which has both instance data *and* related functions on the same object (the class instance) can make code a lot cleaner.

Of course, you don't ever *have* to use a class if you don't want to, but that's one possible benefit.

Comment: https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/insights/2019/onepattern using classes allows your team to draw out a design in 5 minutes. It is very powerful.  Even when not needed, use classes and wire up business classes through constructors and pass DTO classes/request/response/databaseObjects through methods.  Separate how business/functions are wired up from the execution and it makes maintenance much faster in a team of 3+ developers.

Answer (score 0):

With the example you have given, you indeed have a point:

- a function that validates an email does not really need an instantiated object to act on, and in fact you want to run it *before* creating the API's object instance.
- a function that really returns a *different* object (`user` is not an instance of `User`) without mutating the `this` object, is also not the best reason for a separate class. If this (email verification) is all you will ever need to do as "extra" compared to the API's object class you already have access to (which returns `user`), then the second way is fine.

If however, you will have several other functionalities you want to *extend* that API with, like there could be:

- preparing a personalised email for which you would need their name, address, email, gender,...
- returning some calculated score based on several properties (age, last login date, access level, ...)
- ...

...then it might become nicer to use the first pattern -- although still a matter of opinion.

I would suggest to still create your own class, but to let it create the API's object immediately, and make the returned object value a property of your own instance. This new object is then a composition of the API's interface with your own extensions to it.

Maybe like so:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    // whatever function that checks if an email is valid
    if (email === 'notValid') {
        throw new Error();
    }
}

class User  {
    constructor(email) {
        this.rank = 10; // Let's say you need this property that is not offered by the API
        validateEmail(email);
        // whatever function that inserts user in the database
        this.apiUser = api.createUser(email);
    }

    promote() { // Some function using the new properties
        if (this.rank > 1) this.rank--;
    }

    prepareEmail() { // Other function using a mix
        return {
            sentBy: "admin@mysite.com",
            to: this.apiUser.get("email"),
            body: `Dear ${this.apiUser.get("name")}, your current rank is ${this.rank}`
        };
    }
}

const user = new User('test@test.com');
```

So, here you see that the main code creates one object instance. The API's object instance is encapsulated inside it. You could either allow the caller to work directly with the API, using `user.apiUser.someApiMember` syntax, or you could create your own wrapper functions in your own class, to be accessed as `user.myApiWrapperMember`.